# Argo CD timeout when creating an application

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, cicd, argocd

Hello I setup a new ArgoCD instance, which I successfully connected to my private gitlab repository:
[image]

But it seems that it's timeouting when I try to create an application:

```
time="2021-12-26T10:28:21Z" level=error msg="finished unary call with code Internal" error="rpc error: code = Internal desc = Failed to fetch 77f31050a59a475378ae0dc712d5f84421760aac: `git fetch origin --tags --force` failed timeout after 1m30s" grpc.code=Internal grpc.method=GetAppDetails grpc.request.deadline="2021-12-26T10:01:29Z" grpc.service=repository.RepoServerService grpc.start_time="2021-12-26T10:00:29Z" grpc.time_ms=1.6724298e+06 span.kind=server system=grpc
```

Any idea on this issue? I know there's a bug with private gitlab repositories on a specific port, but I tried with both URLs (with and without the "ssh://") without success